# Replacing JASPERSOFT logo with custom logo

Tags: mysql, background, jasperserver, graphical-logo

I've been trying to replace the logo and background image from JASPERSOFT CE using the two simple methods that were posted in the company document.The problem I face is that it loads from the MYSQL database

_THEMES\5A5D753\IMAGES\LOGO.PNG

instead of

THEMES\IMAGES\LOGO.PNG

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Ask them to support you.

Comment: I did mail them my query quite a few times...but they seem to be taking a lot of time to reply to my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out how to work this out !

Straight forward method is to

1.create a new folder and rename it (your choice) for this answer I will call it "green"

2.inside the folder "green" create a new folder called "images"'

3.Paste your logo.png file here

4.Start jasperserver login as admin or superuser

5.In the themes icon right click and choose "Add Folder" name it the same as "green"

6.Right click the folder "green" and choose "Add Resource"

7.Next choose "Add Image"

8.Enter the same name and type of file eg "logo.png" click submit

9.Now right click the green folder and click "set as active theme" and voila you're done !

I believe in free knowledge if any one wants the documentation I prepared for this please ask me I will email them to you

Thanks

Comment: bro i need document , i tried these step but i failed .   Shubham.batra17@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

Vinner - paid support would give you and answer right away.

Anyways, you're not setting the theme as "active" in the repository. You must log in as a super user, find your theme and right click "Set as active theme"

Comment: you are right Ernesto...I googled a bit more after your reply and got my answer thanks for your valuable input. Just to point out though Community Edition does not have a SUPERUSER